# What is the probability that he will sit on his/her seat?

Tags: probability, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

A room has 25 seats. There are 25 people in a queue. People enter the room one by one. 1st person in the queue does not know his/her seat. Others know their seats. 1st person sits randomly. If next person's seat is empty then he will sit on his/her seat. If not, he/she will sit randomly. What is the probability of 25th person that he/she will sit on his/her seat?

Comment: Such a bullet-speed duplicate @Henry!

Comment: @JaideepKhare  If it is a classic question with no effort from the person asking, it seems simple enough